# How to use a ternary operator to convert a String that can sometimes be null into an integer in Java?

Tags: java, logic, talend

I am using Talend to filter out some rows from an excel file and they don't allow block statements. Everything has to be simple logic or using the ternary operator. So the problem is that the code/logic I need will be used across every cell in the column, BUT some of the cells are `null`, some are `Strings` and the rest are `Strings` that represent `integers`.

My logic needs to be this:
`Return true if and only if PlanName == null || PlanName == 0` but as you can tell, it will fail when it tries to run this on a cell that contains the `null` or the cell that contains a String that isn't a number.

Is it possible to have this logic in java without the try-catch or block statements? This is what I have right now:

```
input_row.PlanName == null || Integer.parseInt(input_row.PlanName) == 0
```

Thanks!

Edit: Basically, I just need to write logic that does this:
**Return true if `input_row.PlanName == null` OR if input_row.PlanName == 0**
This needs to be done without using block-statements or try-catches because I am using Talend. So I can only use logical operators like `&&` and `||` and I can use ternary operators as well.

Comment: Your explanation is vague and somewhat equivocal. Clarify what you want to achieve. *My logic needs to be this: Return true if and only if PlanName == null || PlanName == 0 but as you can tell, it will fail when it tries to run this on a cell that contains the null* - why it will fail? it will not, as `||` is a short circuit.

Comment: It will fail because not every cell contains an int. Some are null and some are strings that aren't integers so yes it fails. I get a number format exception.

Comment: *Return true if and only if PlanName == null || PlanName == 0* - will not fail if the `PlanName` is null. Second operand will NOT be evaluated. Can you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: Yes but it will fail if the text is "text"

Comment: Please provide the code that you have so far.

Comment: What I have posted is all of the code I have so far. In Talend you just put in logic so there is no other code to it. I just have `input_row.PlanName == null || Integer.parseInt(input_row.PlanName) == 0`

Comment: Is, `input_row.PlanName == null || Integer.parseInt(input_row.PlanName) == 0` is legit. Now, what you don't like in this and what you want to achieve? edit your question and narrow it down to specific question, please. I have no idea what is *Talend* but your question is about Java..

Comment: *Is it possible to have this logic in java without the try-catch or block statements?* - Yes, if you will throw the exception to one level above (caller). You must either catch it and process in the method, or throw it to the caller (one level above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, i'll go for routines : reusable bunch of code, handy for this kind of rules that would be hard to implement without if/else etc.

You can create two Routines in Talend, with static methods that you would be able to use in a tMap or a tJavaRow.

First Routine to know if your plan is a numeric or not :

```
  public static boolean isNumeric(String strNum) {
        if (strNum == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            double d = Double.parseDouble(strNum);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then another routine like :

```
public static boolean correctPlanName(String planName) {
   if(Relational.ISNULL(planName)){
   return false;
   }
   else{
       if(!isNumeric(planName)){
           return false;
       }
       else {
          return true;
       }
   }
```

}
Then you call Routines.correctPlanName(input_row.planName) in tMap/tJavaRow.
It should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *regular expression* to check if the String only contains digits, then check if `num == 0`.

```
input_row.PlanName == null || (input_row.PlanName != null && input_row.PlanName.matches("\\d+") && Integer.parseInt(input_row.PlanName) == 0)
```

Edit: Probably overkill but to cover other cases e.g. floating point types, numbers prefixed with `+`/`-`, you could also do:

```
input_row.PlanName != null && input_row.PlanName.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+") && Double.parseDouble(input_row.PlanName) == 0)
```

Comment: Not all series of digits can be parsed into an `int` and you don't allow for negative numbers or numbers preceded by a `+` etc.

Comment: Good point, my first answer was based on the following assumption from OP's question: `some of the cells are null, some are Strings and the rest are Strings that represent integers`.